# Facebook moving messages to Messenger?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, facebook

After updating to Ubuntu 33 (OTA-11) I get a warning to move to Messenger after tapping messages on the Ubuntu Touch Facebook web app.
Does anybody know if they will move the feature over to the app? Are there plans/discussion of a Messenger app for the phone and tablet versions of Ubuntu Touch?

A screenshot of the warning to install the Messenger app:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The message that you are getting is coming from Facebook, not Ubuntu. I get the same message on my phone, but I do not choose to add it, so I see it everytime I go to facebook. Here are two posts that could help you understand more:

1. [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200236345979960)
2. [Messenger For Desktop](https://messengerfordesktop.com/)

Comment: They have been threatening this for months now... Luckily, as often happens with guys trying to be bullies, they threaten a lot but they never take action. It seems they like to annoy their users.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I can't use Messenger for Desktop or any other 3rd party app on the phone. The first is not compatible with Ubuntu Touch and in the spring of 2015 Facebook deprecated their XMPP api so none of the apps mentioned in the first link will work.

Comment: It is an annoyance, you just need to tell it not to use messenger, and it will take you to the regular messenger page.  Until FB gets up to date with Ubuntu, this will be happening.  Not much else that can be done.  Unless anyone else here has a better answer.....

Answer (score 1):

There are two apps in the store which may be useful:

- [Messenger](https://uappexplorer.com/app/messenger.vocoderism) by *Davide Franzino* for **tablets**
- [Fmessenger](https://uappexplorer.com/app/fmessenger.hankamotz) by *Hankamotz* for **phones**